# How to reference an eval variable in query

Tags: splunk

I am trying to access a variable (in this example; `sampleFromDate` and `sampleToDate`) from a sub-query. I have defined the variables with syntax `eval variableName = value` and would like to access with syntax `filterName=$variableName$`. See the example below where I am trying to access values using `earliest=$sampleFromDate$ latest=$sampleToDate$`

```
index=*
earliest=-8d latest=-1d
| eval sampleToDate=now()
| eval sampleFromDate=relative_time(now(), "-1d")
| appendcols [
    search (index=*)
    earliest=$sampleFromDate$ latest=$sampleToDate$
]
```

This produces the error:

> Invalid value "$sampleFromDate$" for time term 'earliest'

The value of `sampleFromDate` is in the format seconds since epoch time, e.g.

> 1612251236.000000

I know I can do `earliest=-d latest=now()` - but I don't want to do this because I want to reference the variables in several locations and output them at the end.

Comment: The `$foo$` syntax is only valid with tokens or inside the `map` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to `eval` those time values?

Just do:

```
index=* earliest=-8d latest=-1d
| <rest of search>
| appendcols [
    search (index=*) earliest=-1d
    | <rest of appended search>
]
```

There's no need to explicitly set `latest` unless you want something *other than* `now()`

Comment: Thanks.  In this case I do want something other than `now()`